# Can I run Cypress tests on Iphone and Android using different browsers?

Tags: cypress

Can anybody let me know if it is actually possible to run Cypress tests on real phone or
on Android Studio emulator and Xcode simulator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you go through [cypress official website](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/general-questions-faq#Do-you-support-native-mobile-apps), they have clearly mentioned that **cypress will NOT run on native mobile app**. So we can not run cypress on a real phone or simulator or emulator.
However, cypress supports testing different viewports to test web pages in mobile view.

> Cypress will never be able to run on a native mobile app, but we can
> test some functionality of mobile web browsers and test mobile
> applications that are developed in a browser, such as with [the Ionic
> framework](https://ionicframework.com/).
>
> Currently you can control the viewport with the [cy.viewport()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/viewport) command
> to test responsive, mobile views in a website or web application. You
> can also mimic certain behaviors like swiping using [custom commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands).
>
> You can read about testing mobile applications with Ionic and Cypress
> [here](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/07/08/end-to-end-testing-mobile-apps-with-ionic-and-cypress/) and see how we manage testing the mobile viewport in the [Cypress
> Real World App](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app).

[Source](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/general-questions-faq#Do-you-support-native-mobile-apps)

Comment: " cypress supports testing different viewports to test web pages in mobile devices." this means I can run cypress on real devices ?

Comment: @donmezburak Cypress can not run on real mobile devices. I have updated the sentence.  Using cypress we can test websites or web applications in mobile views but not the native apps.

Comment: So basically: no, you can't test on actual mobile devices. But you can fake it by setting the viewport to the size of the device... not 100% fidelity but close.

Comment: @TimKeating lets say, the website have different code for mobile and desktop, then for a particular route. How we can test both views i.e mobile and desktop

Comment: That doesn't have an easy answer. I would have to understand why you are doing that, and how you are determining that the user is on mobile vs. desktop (assuming it's something other than viewport dimensions). User agent detection? That's a bad idea: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent. Best answer I can give you is to determine how you are differentiating the platforms, and find a way to fake that.